# Is it normal for a lever-style tap to only introduce cold water into the mix when it's at a higher level?

Tags: water, faucet, sink

I have a lever tap fitted to one of the sinks in my property; up/down controls the speed of the water flow, and left/right the temperature - further left is hotter, and right is cooler.

I've noticed that the slower the water flow coming out of the tap (i.e. when the lever is only slightly pushed up) that the temperature of the water seems to be much hotter than when the lever is pushed all the way up - this is observed even when the lever is in the middle position. Is this by design for most of these lever-style taps? My assumption is that the tap is only releasing hot water when the lever is only slightly pushed up, but then introduces cold into the mix the further up it is pushed.

Comment: Is your home equipped with a hot-water recirculating pump?

Comment: Yes - apologies for not mentioning this. I have a hot water tank fitted.

Comment: The valve plate is actuated by lifting the lever all that happen is 2 orings slide over the supply’s the further up you pull the handle the more the o ring allows in , just move the handle slightly to the left if you don’t think it is warm enough. Both orings are on a single plate. Hot water has more restrictions than cold because of the water heater, if you want them the same a pressure regulator on each line would be the way to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I would first take it apart and see if there is some sort of restriction in the cold water side of the valve or some other problem with the valve internals, as this is a fairly easy check.

The valve is designed so that the orifices delivering hot and cold are open equally when the lever is in the neutral position (the tap doesn't know anything about temperature, just variable orifice size depending on lever position). Any difference in pressure between hot and cold supply could make "neutral" something other than what you expect due to difference in flow rate between hot and cold. Along the same line of thinking, unusually hot (or cold) supply could also make "neutral" something different than you expect. At high flow rates perhaps this difference would be less obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the tap is supplied via some kind of "instant heat" water heater off the mains water supply rather than being supplied from tanks.

This means you get several effects. They are more noticeable if you have separate taps but they still happen with a mixer.

Firstly the water temperature from the water heater may vary with the flow rate. This is certainly noticeable with mine. Under low flow the water is very hot, but with the bath tap wide-open it drops to being merely hot.

Secondly the pressure/flow curves for the hot and cold feeds will be different. The heater will act as a restriction, so the pressure in the hot feed will drop off more steeply with flow than the cold feed.

Thirdly since both hot and cold come from the same ultimate source and the hot path is more restricted, the cold path can "starve" the hot path.

Put all these things together and opening the tap up wider, while keeping the same ratio you are likely to get colder water, perhaps significantly so. I know when filling my bath I have the hot tap wide open and the cold tap only open a small amount.